# How to link into a cart outside of magento that was built with the cart api's

Tags: php, magento

I am building a custom front end to Magento, where users selects the products they want to purchase outside of Magento. But then use Magento for the rest.

I already use the product api's to pull the product_id/sku/name/price out. So I have a list of product_id’s ready for purchase.

I will use the api's for creating and building a shopping cart.

My question is…
Once I populate a shopping cart using the apis and have the shoppingcart_id, how do I redirect the user directly into that shopping cart page in Magento?

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting is easy. This is how you can do it in Magento 1.5. Note that you need to be running within a controller action in order for this to work properly.

```
$this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
```

If you want to direct the user to the checkout page, try something like the following:

```
$this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Misread the question, sorry! Conceptually speaking, you'd need to create a checkout session for the current user and pass that session into Magento so it knows who is the owner of the current cart; you'd probably direct the user to http://www.example.com/checkout/cart